# Esp8266 Arducam- uploading to external IP

Tags: python, server, camera, arduino, esp8266

I have an Arducam OV2640

There is a lot of documentation on how the code works wth a HTML and js script which calls the camera IP address, after arducam creates a web server.

This web server listens to get requests and sends a post response of the image.

The only problem is this is all over local wifi...source:

https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/tree/master/ArduCAM/examples/ESP8266/ArduCAM_ESP8266_OV2640_Capture

Has anyone done anything such as sending to Imgur via api or for instance a cloud based program like python anywhere?

I've been trying different methods all day, but a lot it comes to people saying "you need to send each byte and the other side have a handler."

I'm asking because the local wifi method works so easily I thought there must be a way to extend this to external addresses in a nicer way?

Has anyone done or heard of anything like this?

Thanks

Comment: just use a script to copy it from your local address to a cloud server; maybe on a cron-job or something fancier if you need low-latency